# Send Data To All Instances In A Managed Service on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rtmp, google-cloud-load-balancer

On Google Cloud Platform, I am trying to have an RTMP stream go to a load balancer, and then have that load balancer distribute the stream to all the instances behind a managed service. Meaning that the LB shouldn't use things like Round Robin or CPU utilization, it should just go to all the instances.

The use case scenario is the infrastructure is designed to be a push (over pull). In my managed instances, I have several Node Media Servers that auto-scale based CPU utilized because the RTMP stream is be converted to HLS. Now each instance will require its own stream to be pushed into it for the conversion to occur and the user to recieve the stream content.

How can this done at GCP if not with a load balancer?

Comment: That is not what load balancers do. Load balancers distribute load (requests), they do not broadcast load.

Comment: @JohnHanley Then what would broadcast content to all instances in a Managed Group?

Comment: Google does not provide a service that supports request broadcasting to VM instances. I do not understand why you think you need one. For content distribution, you want the opposite. One or more instances send streams to many clients.

Comment: The infrastructure is designed to be a push (over pull). In my managed instances, I have several Node Media Servers that auto-scale based CPU utilized because the RTMP stream is be converted to HLS. Now each instance will require its own stream to be pushed into it for the conversion to occur and the user to recieve the stream content.

Comment: Please edit your post to clearly describe the implementation. Based on what you have described, why do you think you need a load balancer?

Comment: @JohnHanley I thought a load balancer could accomplish this but I guess I was mistaen.

Comment: After your last update, I still do not understand exactly what you are trying to do (implementation details). You have not clearly defined a problem to be solved. Perhaps a graph to show how you are interconnecting everything and showing what triggers what.